# How to install lxml for PyPy?

Tags: lxml, pypy

I've created a virtualenv for PyPy with:

```
virtualenv test -p `which pypy`
source test/bin/activate
```

I installed the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

And then I run:

```
pip install --upgrade pypy
```

As a result I get a lot of errors looking like this:

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:234038:22: error: `PyThreadState` {aka struct _ts}` has no member named `use_tracing`
```

How do I properly install lxml for PyPy 2.6.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the following fork of lxml for PyPy instead:

https://github.com/aglyzov/lxml/tree/cffi

It can be installed with:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/aglyzov/lxml.git@cffi#egg=lxml-cffi
```

Comment: if someone gets "permission denied" during "import lxml" as non-root user then issue the following command once, it will create precompiled cache binaries:
sudo pypy -c 'import lxml'

Comment: `git://` is no longer supported, any chance you could update your answer?