# Speed up beautiful soup with import time (scraping too much irrelevant data)

Tags: python, time, beautifulsoup

My program will run properly and print the desired output, however it takes over a minute to run. It grabs the data for the entire page and then searches through the data for the desired information. The delay is in grabbing the data. Basically what I am looking for is a way to only grab the data for the page containing the desired information instead of grabbing all irrelevant data from the entire page and greatly slowing the process.

The information I require is the first chunk of data that contains both "$" and "LDK2-ENY10", the variable z is used to only grab the first chunk of data and not all irrelevant data afterwards.

```
import requests
from time import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup     
z = 0;
link = "http://yugiohprices.com/get_card_prices/Dark+Magician?_={}"
r = requests.get(link.format(int(time())))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
rawdata = soup.find_all("td")
for thing in rawdata:    
  if "LDK2-ENY10" in str(thing) and "$" in str(thing) and z == 0:
    print thing; z = 1;
```

This is the current output, It would probably be fast enough with just scraping this output, it seems a little redundant since I only require the information from lines 10 (`<b>$0.33</b>`), 18 (`$0.77`), and 29 (`$5.28`), however at this point I don't care and just want the program to run without taking 2-5 minutes.. (30 seconds or less would be amazing)

Please let me know if there is anything missing from my post and I will update it.

```
<td style="width: 206px; padding-right: 10px" valign="top">
<table border="1" id="item_stats" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
              Lowest
              <a alt="How are lowest prices calculated?" href="http://blog.yugiohprices.com/post/90183367316/lowest-card-price-is-now-picked-using-ebay-listings" target="_blank" title="How are lowest prices calculated?">(?)</a>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 2px">
<b>$0.33</b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">Highest</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 2px">
                $5.28
              </p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
              Average
              <a alt="How are average prices calculated?" href="http://blog.yugiohprices.com/post/54460976914/how-are-average-prices-calculated" target="_blank" title="How are average prices calculated?">(?)</a>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 2px">
                $0.77
              </p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" id="item_stats">
<tr style="height: 22px">
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 80px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>
                  Shift
                </b>
<br/>
                (24 Hours)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b style="color: red">
                  -9.41%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 80px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (3 Days)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b style="color: red">
                  -2.53%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 80px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (1 Week)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b style="color: red">
                  -9.41%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (3 Weeks)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b>
                  0%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (30 Days)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b>
                  0%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (3 Months)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b>
                  0%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (6 Months)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b>
                  0%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 94px">
<p style="margin-top: -6px; margin-bottom: -4px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; font-weight: normal">
<b>Shift</b>
<br/>
                (1 Year)
              </p>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center">
<p style="margin: 6px; margin-bottom: 9px">
<b>
                  0%
                </b>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="key" colspan="2" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000">
<a href="/price_history/LDK2-ENY10?rarity=Common" target="_blank">View History</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div align="center">
<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Yugioh Prices Skyscraper -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7333610178228936" data-ad-slot="9136249004" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"></ins>
<script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
          </script>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the odds parsing is the bottleneck here are pretty low - please recheck that assumption.

---

The first logical thing is to get rid of the `z` variable and simply *break the loop* once the desire information was found. This should have a significant impact on the execution time:

```
for thing in rawdata:    
    thing_html = str(thing)  # avoiding calling str() two times per iteration
    if "LDK2-ENY10" in thing_html and "$" in thing_html:
        print(thing)
        break
```

---

Or/and, you can avoid parsing the complete page source and [parse only a part of the document with the `SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document). Something along these lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

td_only = SoupStrainer("td")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml", parse_only=td_only)
```

Though, I doubt the "parse only" approach would have a significant impact given the relatively small size of the tree.

---

An other thing you can try is running the script with the [`PyPy`](http://pypy.org/) interpreter instead of a regular `CPython`. You would need to switch from `lxml` to `html.parser` or `html5lib` (or you can [install `lxml` from the fork](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34166494/771848)), but, after few quick tests I can see that performing better than `CPython` + `lxml`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how frustrating this was getting >.< I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you I believe I have it marked as resolved now.  1 last question, would you happen to know if there is a way to only load the <p> tags within <td> tags? or a way to only load the first few tags? I apologize for being so new at this